# Wiring for irrigation pump

Tags: wiring

I have a 115/230v 14/8/7.4 amp pump that I will be using to pull water from a stream to irrigate the property. The wire will be run through pvc conduit and buried about 18-24" deep. The water will be pumped uphill about 200' to a valve system and switch in a water proof housing. The switch will be fed by a wire running approx 100' to an interior meter box in the shop where it will be connected to 30 amp service. I was told I should use #6 AWG and I believe I need to use 3 strand. Does that sound about right?

Comment: 30A service or 30A breaker? What are the 14/8/7.4 numbers? Is it a combined 115V/230V - i.e., it uses *both* 115V and 230V at the same time? Or is it configurable to run on 115V **or** on 230V? Makes a big difference in voltage drop/wire sizing.

Comment: Side thought: do you have water rights to divert from the stream? Some governments get picky about that sort of thing.